# send ajax and if there's a specific object in json response send next request to this object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i want to send ajax request to a url and the response is json its has 2 object ; first is group_id second object is next_page. i want to send next ajax request if isset next_page and request url will be next_page value if there isn't next_page stop ajax requesting.
this is my javascript code but not working :

```
     $("#getUsersId").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
var Keyword = $('#Keyword').val();
var fbAcc = $("#fbAccs").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'exGoupsReq.php',
            data:{Keyword: Keyword,fb_acc: fbAcc},
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#addFbAcc').css("opacity",".5");
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('.successMSG').html('');
                if(response[0].next_page){
                console.log(response[0].next_page);

                    // if is set next_page then send ajax request to next_page
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'exGoupsReq.php?next='+response[0].next_page,
                        data:{Keyword: Keyword,fb_acc: fbAcc},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function(){
                        },
                        success: function(response2){
                            if(response[0].next_page){

                                $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'exGoupsReq.php?next='+response2[0].next_page,
                                data:{Keyword: Keyword,fb_acc: fbAcc},
                                dataType: 'json',
                                beforeSend: function(){
                                },
                                success: function(response){

                                }


                            });

                        }

                        }


                    });


                }else{
                    $('.successMSG').html(
                         Swal.fire({
                              icon: 'danger',
                              title: response.message,
                              showConfirmButton: false,
                              timer: 2000,
                              timerProgressBar: true
                            }).then(function(isConfirm) {
                              if (isConfirm) {
                                
                              } else {
                                //if no clicked => do something else
                              }
                            })
                            );
                }
                $('#addFbAcc').css("opacity","");
                $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });



});
```

and this is the json response:

```
[{"group_id":"3227753957460161","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"634745371303934","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"623523731538627","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"874339386716003","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"327802997885129","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"1213445152028414","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"310298904216864","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"2630210850348811","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"234662357739095","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"591588044857727","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"3348702175450922","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"101162043569757","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"},{"group_id":"2287318904779687","next_page":"/smm/nextpage.php?id=jkldt5u437VpRx57AZF_SwJok0Qj5Nkcma8LUb_AKz1agfMs_5YFb1Gf2cI2_6t8fSrE_fqZ-cbex-CIJf4meZjFWkBU87OnJrxUP6wWdGkV4kOqCexzbBpjEXQVwKzg8H7XAJw2ZfHLbCvacn1Q9I6Hh4C0Z6sD_eVOaPyTMWqVZsA&pn=2&usid=34fcde099323ec03cc2630d7e4b36988&tsid&refid=46"}]
```

Comment: `not working` more specific please.  What's the error?  What result do you get in the network tab for this request?

Comment: @James there isn't response.next_page so it runs code inside else condition

Comment: Ah yes, there won't be a response.next_page.  There would be a response[0].next_page and a response[1].next_page, since you modified the output to be an array.  Which one will you use?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes it works but it send only 1 request after main ajax request

Comment: @James yes it works but it send only 1 request after main ajax request

Comment: I'm not seeing `response.message` in your JSON. What will your response look like whenever there is an error?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier i edit the post, it send main ajax request and if there is `next_page ` it send second ajax to `next_page ` then stopp , i want it to send ajax request to `next_page ` until theres no  `next_page `then stop

Comment: I understand, though you didn't answer my question about `response.message`. I don't believe your second URL will now work as it should result to `exGoupsReq.php?next=/smm/nextpage.php?id={yourverylongid}` Which is not a valid URL. Or has the response changed as well?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier `exGoupsReq.php?next=/smm/nextpage.php?id=` i was replaced real url for privacy but it's a valid url like `https://stackoverflow.com/?nextpage.php?id=`

Comment: It is still unclear where `response.message` comes from. I can't solve your code without knowing when the `message` property exists.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier `/smm/nextpage.php?id=` it's a web page i'm scraping data from it using php and i return this data as a json in this page `exGoupsReq.php?next=` and there's a button like pagination is named `next page` i want to send second ajax request to this next page using my  `exGoupsReq.php?next=` to get the second data from it , the response it return from ajax request .I wish I was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code so that it uses a *recursive* function. That means that whenever there is a next page, it will fetch it and keeps doing this untill there are no more next pages to fetch.

```
async function scrapePage(url, data = {}) {
  const response = await $.ajax({
    url,
    data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
  });

  // If there is no next page, show the error.
  const nextPage = response[0]?.next_page;
  if (typeof nextPage === 'undefined') {
    $(".successMSG").html(
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "danger",
        title: "No more pages",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 2000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
      }).then(function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
        } else {
          //if no clicked => do something else
        }
      })
    );

    return;
  }

  // Otherwise scrape the next page.
  await scrapePage(nextPage, data);
}

$("#getUsersId").on("submit", async function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var keyword = $("#Keyword").val();
  var fbAcc = $("#fbAccs").val();

  const data = { 
    Keyword: keyword, 
    fb_acc: fbAcc 
  };

  $(".submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  await scrapePage("exGoupsReq.php", data);

  $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```
.submitBtn:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: thank you it works , Can I stop the requests after 50 requests how cant make , Sorry for so many questions, I'm still a beginner in JavaScript

Comment: That's alright, glad to help out. Might I suggest that you try to figure it out yourself firs, then if you're struggling create a new question and tag me in the comments if you need *my* help, though I'm sure you'll get an answer pretty fast.